# difference between intersecting, weakly and crossing supermodular functions

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, algorithms, operations-research

Am reading some texts on algorithms and I am confused with the differences between these definitions I read in several texts.

Given a set $V$, we have these types of set functions $f:V \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$

1) Crossing Supermodular: a set function $f$ is crossing supermodular if for every $A,B \subseteq V$ s.t. $A \cap B \neq \emptyset$ and $A \cup B \neq V$, we have:

$$
f(A) + f(B) \leq f(A \cap B) + f(A\cup B) \quad \text{Eq. 1}
$$

2) Intersecting Supermodular: a set function $f$ is intersecting supermodular if  Eq. $1$ holds whenever $A$ and $B$ are intersecting.

3) Weakly Supermodular: a set function $f$ is weakly supermodular if for every $A,B \subseteq V$, one of the following holds:

$$
f(A) + f(B) \leq f(A \cap B) + f(A \cup B)
$$
$$
f(A) + f(B) \leq f(A - B) + f(B-A)
$$

I am not sure how these three definitions differ or if $(2)$ and $(3)$ are actually equivalent.. Are there any examples to help me understand these three?

Comment: As written, (2) and (3) are not equivalent. For instance take $V=\{1,2\}$ where $f(\emptyset)=-1$, $f(\{1\})=0$, $f(\{2\})=0$, and $f(\{1,2\})=0$. This satisfies (2) but not (3).

Comment: Let $V={1,2,3}$ and let $f(\emptyset)=7$, $f(\{1\})=2$, $f(\{2\})=0$, $f(\{3\})=2$, $f(\{1,2\})=1$, $f(\{1,3\})=0$, $f(\{2,3\})=1$, and $f(\{1,2,3\})=1$. This satisfies (3) but not (2).

Comment: @parafoo, thanks, is there an example that satisfies (2) but not (1)?

Comment: Every $f$ that satisfies (2) will satisfy (1). Let $f$ satisfy (2). To show it satisfies (1), we must show that if $A,B \subseteq V$ where $A \cap B \not= \emptyset$ and $A \cup B \not= V$ then Eq 1 holds for $A$ and $B$. Well since we assume $A\cap B \not=\emptyset$, we have that $A$ and $B$ are intersecting. Therefore, statement 2 implies that $A$ and $B$ satisfy equation 1. Hence, a function that satisfies (2) will always satisfy (1).